# konica bizhub c220 unable to scan to smb

Tags: network-share, server-message-block

Setup:
We have office network setup on workgroup. There is a one Konica Minolta Bizhub C220.

Problem:
Unable to scan to PC(SMB) folders on couple computers, getting error 57 - Failed to connect to the server

When it start:
I have change a router, I use occasion to rename PC and setup static IP. From this time I have problem.

So this is my problem. I try to setup dynamic IP, I compare settings with PC where scanning working, create new folder, create new "user" on Konica, disabled firewall... I think I have done most things.... But still have this error 57 and I'm unable to scan. And it's only on 3 PC. Maybe you have idea what could be a problem? I contact Konica and they told me this is IT issue so they are unable to help.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: This is almost certainly an SMB v1 issue. What version of Windows do you have on the three machines that don't work? Do you have any PCs at all that can receive scans, and if so, what version of Windows on those?

Comment: All PC running on Windows 10 Pro. Like I mention I change router (this is not relevant, I think) and on the same time I change names of PC and setup static IP, after this I get problem to scan.

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable SMB v1 in windows features to enable this scan function again, becasue smb v1 disable in new windows 10 features